# What is a hamburger menu and what is it used for?

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, hamburger-menu

What is the "3 Line Menu" or "Hamburger Menu"?

How is it useful? What is its purpose within an application or website?

Answer (score 4):

You may also see the **Hamburger Menu** be referred to as:

- **Hotdog Menu**
- **Three-line Menu**
- **Pancake Menu**
- **Options Menu**
- **Kebab Menu**

It gets these names from the typical appearance of the menu icon:

> [image: Source: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/hamburger-menu.htm]
>
> **Fig. 1:** The hamburger menu icon (highlighted in red) as seen in *Mozilla Firefox* 2017.

When the icon is pressed a menu slides across the screen or pops up. 
When the user re-clicks the icon or a region outside of the menu, or in some cases swipes, it will hide itself again.

An example of an open **Hamburger Menu** can be seen below:

> [image: Source: http://cdn.ilovefreesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Extra-Browsing-Options.png]
>
> **Fig. 2:** An open "pop-up" style hamburger menu as seen in *Atlas Web Browser for Android* 2014.

And another example:

> [image: Source: http://media.tumblr.com/a0714a6b9fd605bea3631b5c0e7ff561/tumblr_inline_mw8n4sAc1e1sqe4gp.png]
>
> **Fig. 3:** An open "sliding" style hamburger menu as seen in *YouTube App for Android* 2013.

---

## Purpose

The **Hamburger Menu** is ideal for mobile devices because the menu is hidden, thus freeing space for content.

The primary downside of the **Hamburger Menu** is that it is less noticeable. Therefore I would recommend only using it when space is critical such as in a mobile app.

With that said, a **Hamburger Menu** can be used as a *secondary menu* in conjunction with a main one. This could be useful for web development.

For example, take a look at this current desktop webpage (2017) now. You will see the main menu items along the top: *Questions, Developer Jobs, Documentation, Tags, Users*.

Then if you look to the right there are **Hamburger Menu's** for secondary menu items: *Inbox, Achievements, Help, Stack Exchange Sites*. 
It just so happens that the icons are unique to make it more clear what the list is, but the farthest right one is a clever combination of the typical hamburger icon infused with a speech bubble.

---

## References

- http://www.nightsprout.com/blog/hamburger-menus-and-how-to-make-them.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button
- https://uxplanet.org/when-to-use-a-hamburger-menu-199d62f764aa
- http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-31602745

Answer (score 0):

**What Is the Hamburger Menu?**

The hamburger menu (which doesn’t come with a side order of fries) is the three horizontal lines you see now at the top of many screens, either on the far left or the far right.

In the real case it was an Icon.

**Uses of Hamburger Menu :**

By touching, tapping or clicking on the icon, it opens up a side menu with a selection of options or additional pages.

Some developers love the hamburger 3 line menu icon because it enables them to pack more features into their apps or navigation. The tiny icon takes up a minimal amount of screen real estate. It gives the app or site a clean minimalist look.

Answer (score 0):

The hamburger menu is a name given to the menu icon found responsive websites that hides the traditional File menu.On pressing the icon the menu drops down with some animation providing your website a great look and feel.It is generally used for making websites look good in mobile phones in order to make them responsive.

Answer (score -1):

The hamburger menu is a 3 or 4 horizontal line image which is called hamburger.